# Get primary key of Eloquent model instance

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I'm happy enough to work on a project with (not) very consistent column names in our MySQL database. We have camelCase, PascalCase, 'Id', ID and it's driving me nuts. I've decided to start using Eloquent in our application (which is NOT Laravel). I would love to have a method of receiving the value of the primary key easily without knowing the column name e.g.

```
// User's primary key column is called UserID
$user = User::find(1337);
$userId = $user->id(); // = 1337
```

Is there a Eloquent way of doing this or am I gonna have to add this method myself?

Comment: Are you asking whether this is eloquent ?

Comment: Mark said is correct but although you can use mutators in all your model for consistence name like id() (function within model)  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You should have define a protected field in your model telling Eloquent what the primary key column is:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'guid';
```

Then you can access that property in your model

The model's `getKey()` method should give you value of the primary key, while `getKeyName()` should tell you what column name is used for the primary key

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it dynamically -

```
app("App\\Models\\" . $modelName)->getKeyName();//Laravel 8
app("App\\" . $modelName)->getKeyName();//Laravel less than 8
```